# Regex matching on full matched substring with constrains in Python

Tags: python, regex

*Since it's a regex question. This is a potential duplicated question.*

Considering those given strings

```
test_str = [
    "bla bla google.com bla bla", #0
    "bla bla www.google.com bla bla", #1
    "bla bla api.google.com bla bla", #2
    "google.com", #3
    "www.google.com", #4
    "api.google.com", #5
    "http://google.com", #6
    "http://www.google.com", #7
    "http://api.google.com", #8
    "bla bla http://www.google.com bla bla", #9
    "bla bla https://www.api.google.com bla bla" #10
]
```

My desired return is `google.*` or `www.google.*` but not `api.google.*`. Which means, in above case, 2, 5, 8, 10 should not return any match.

---

I have tried several regex, but I can not find a one line regex string for doing this tasks. Here are what I tried.

```
re.compile("((http[s]?://)?www\.google[a-z.]*)") # match 1,4,7,9
re.compile("((http[s]?://)?google[a-z.]*)") # match all
re.compile("((http[s]?://)?.+\.google[a-z.]*)") # match except 0,3,6
re.compile("((http[s]?://)?!.+\.google[a-z.]*)") # match nothing
```

Here, I am seeking a way to ignore `*.google.*` except `www.google.*` and `google.*`. But I got stuck while finding a way to get `*.google.*`.

---

PS: I have found a O(n**2) way with `split()` to solve this.

```
r = re.compile("^((http[s]?://)?www.google[a-z.]*)|^((http[s]?://)?google[a-z.]*)")

for s in test_str:
    for seg in s.split():
        r.findall(seg)
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/3Cwfiu

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I have an additional question for your answer. If `api` is not fixed, but I want to filter all of them, such as `map.google.*`, `calendar.google.*`. Is this means that I need to add them one by one?

Comment: You may either use the lookbehind approach, and that means you will have to chain the lookbehinds like `(?<!\bapi)(?<!\bmap)`, or you may use a lookahead based approach, like [`r"(?<!\S)(?!\S*\b(?:map|api))\S*\bgoogle\b\S*"`](https://ideone.com/YswL5x) where you may add the blacklisted terms to the alternation group.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Since it is a blacklist way, I am still curious about a whitelist way.

Comment: For a whitelist approach, I doubt you provided enough data. What are the rules? Only `https?` and `www` (optionally?) before `google`? And only in between whitespaces? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/PUvhUU).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I believe this is what I want. Your assumptions are correct, http(s) and www are options here. I need to learn more about [lookbehinds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Please put your answer below, I will give the answer to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?google\.\S*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW8NkU/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a location preceded with a whitespace or start of a string (note that you may also use `(?:^|\s)` here, to be more explicit)
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence of `https://` or `http://`
- `(?:www\.)?` an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence  of `www.`
- `google\.` - a `google.` substring
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/PUvhUU):

```
import re
test_str = [
    "bla bla google.com bla bla", #0
    "bla bla www.google.com bla bla", #1
    "bla bla api.google.com bla bla", #2
    "google.com", #3
    "www.google.com", #4
    "api.google.com", #5
    "http://google.com", #6
    "http://www.google.com", #7
    "http://api.google.com", #8
    "bla bla http://www.google.com bla bla", #9
    "bla bla https://www.api.google.com bla bla", #10
    "bla bla https://www.map.google.com bla bla" #11
]
r = re.compile(r"(?<!\S)(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?google\.\S*")
for i,s in enumerate(test_str):
    m = r.search(s)
    if m:
        print("{}\t#{}".format(m.group(0), i))
```

Output:

```
google.com  #0
www.google.com  #1
google.com  #3
www.google.com  #4
http://google.com   #6
http://www.google.com   #7
http://www.google.com   #9
```

Answer (score 1):

Had my keyboard been working properly I would have answered a half hour before.

Anyway, I would recommend to not exaggerate the complexity of regexes. You can use the host language to manage black- (and even white-) lists and use the `re` module auxiliary. Below is what I did all packed inside a script. Obviously you may need some restructuring if you have to integrate this code into a class or function:

```
import re

def main():
    input_urls = [ 
        "bla bla google.com bla bla",
        "bla bla www.google.com bla bla",
        # ...
    ]   
    filtered_urls = set()

    google_re = re.compile("(\w+\.)?google.com")
    blacklist = set(["api."])   # I didn't research enough to remove the dot

    for url in input_urls:
        # Beware of the difference between match() and search()
        # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match
        match = google_re.search(url)

        # The second condition will not be evaluated if the first fails
        if match is not None and match.group(1) not in blacklist:
            filtered_urls.add(url)

    print("Accepted URLs:", *filtered_urls, sep="\n\t", end="\n\n")
    print("Blacklisted URLs:", *(set(input_urls).difference(filtered_urls)), sep="\n\t")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately, with my `a` and `h` keyboard keys not working, I wasn't able to quickly find a way to remove the dot in the URL location (like in `api.google`, `www.google`, `calendar.google` and so on). I highly recommend to do that.

The output displayed on my console was:

```
None@vacuum:~$ python3.6 ./filter.py 
Accepted URLs:
    http://google.com
    bla bla google.com bla bla
    bla bla www.google.com bla bla
    http://www.google.com
    google.com
    www.google.com
    bla bla http://www.google.com bla bla

Blacklisted URLs:
    api.google.com
    bla bla api.google.com bla bla
    http://api.google.com
    bla bla https://www.api.google.com bla bla
```